# How to solve ODEs using deep learning in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, packages, machine-learning, code

I have a number of ODEs (58) with 16 parameters and 9 variables. I want to solve the ODEs to obtain the analytical relationship between the parameters and variables. It is obviously that the ODEs cannot be solved using regular analytical methods. It is also not easily solved by simulations since too many parameter sets should be included, and the follow-up fitting should not be easy.
May I solve the ODEs using deep learning methods? Anyone can offer the relevant packages or logics or algorithms? Many many thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a research-level problem to me, which would make it off-topic here. You are probably aware of this paper, as it made quite a buzz when it came out: https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.01412  Going from paper to working Mathematica code is well beyond the scope of StackExchange questions.

Comment: I agree with Szabolcs, to avoid the risk of getting this question closed as off-topic, I suggest you [edit] the question promptly. You can leave your motivation in, but you must reduce the scope of your question to a single particular programming challenge, sharing the code you have tried so far in formatted form and what is stopping you.

Comment: To be clear, maybe in a few years the answer will be "here's the function or package you need to use to solve ODEs symbolically using machine learning". As far as I'm aware, today none of that is available. Here's the code for the paper I referenced: https://github.com/facebookresearch/SymbolicMathematics  That's still some way from usefully solving large systems of ODEs. You'd need to decide what you're interested in: specifically machine-learning-based symbolic math?  Just solving some particular ODE?

Comment: I would contest the statement that "It is obviously that the ODEs cannot be solved using regular analytical methods" and therefore we have to use "deep learning". I would even contest the distinction between "analytical" and "deep learning" methods, and would caution you against putting too much faith into the buzzword of "deep learning". The real questions here are: 1. Can the solution be expressed in terms of elementary functions, or at least "simple" functions? In most cases, the answer is no. This is exactly why we have things like Bessel functions.

Comment: 2. Even if the solution can be expressed in terms of simple functions, is that a useful thing to do? Do you expect a concise solution that will be useful to a human when there are 9 variables and 16 parameters? It seem exceedingly unlikely that such a solution could be simple enough to be useful for anyone. Think about _why_ you want an analytical solution instead of a numerical one, and if an extremely complex solution would fit your purpose (the answer is almost invariably "no")

Comment: Here's a good example about how symbolic solutions are way overrated: The roots of a 3rd order polynomial can be expressed in a closed form. Yet computing numerical values for the roots is often faster with something like Newton's methods than substituting numbers into the closed form.

Comment: @Szabolcs I agree with all your points - I would also add this is a lot like symbolic regression. You could use a genetic algorithm to generate solution candidates - I'm not sure about 'deep learning'. Still, the new expressions would need some kind of regularization on the `LeafCount` to punish overly complex expressions - and the space of expressions is going to be so huge - it's probably not worth it.

Comment: @flinty The method I linked actually produces exact symbolic solutions, but you're right, this may not be what the OP meant. I may have misunderstood the question.  MiaoxiaoWang: Please clarify if this is the case. A summary of the method is here: https://ai.facebook.com/blog/using-neural-networks-to-solve-advanced-mathematics-equations/